# In C++, is there a more efficient way to write multiple declarations

Tags: c++

In C++, is there a more efficient way to write:

```
ImageButton* imageButton;
ImageButton* imageButton1;
ImageButton* imageButton2;
ImageButton* imageButton3;
```

etc without writing out all the lines?  I have over 1000 buttons.  I was hoping there is a better 
way to write this.

Thanks

Comment: Use an array (more specifically `std::array` or `std::vector`). Access them by saying `imageButton[5]` or `imageButton[11]` etc. Remember that arrays start from 0, not 1.

Comment: It's really simple: If you have several of something in programming, don't actually use several. You use a collection. Also, with 1000 buttons usability would be a more pressing issue...

Comment: That *is* a lot of buttons...

Comment: It's not only about declaring pointers, you will have to create objects and set their properties (position, size, image) somehow. Consider this first and then you will come to the simplest way of declaring your variables.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I'll take a look at using `std::array or std::vector`

Comment: There is a very sound principle in any kind of programming. DRY, don't repeat yourself.

Comment: Cheers.  I'm a novice but the penny dropped and I used an array.

Answer (score 4):

If you insist to use a number of variables, do it like this in a line.

```
ImageButton *imageButton, *imageButton1, *imageButton2 ;
```

You can eliminate the stars by a method as well but still this method is almost as worse or better than your.
IT would be better if you use an array of objects.

```
ImageButton [] ;
```

or a dynamic one if you like to grow it afterwards.

```
ImageButton * imagebutton = new ImageButton [size] ;
```

Comment: Arrays are OK, but they usually just cause problems for beginners to them when they don't use the standard containers. That's what they're there for! If the size isn't going to change, `std::array`. Else, or if not using C++11, if the elements are accessed randomly, `std::vector` would do fine. If the elements are being iterated over all the time, `std::list` fits well.

Comment: Agreed...
Better take advantage of the expertise of expert developers rather than making error upon error.

Comment: I used an array in the end but thanks for the answer @CodingMash

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like this:

```
ImageButton *imageButton, *imageButton1, *imageButton2, *imageButton3;
```

In other words, the `*` has to be present for each variable separately.
Or you could do it like this:

```
typedef ImageButton* ImageButtonPtr ;
ImageButtonPtr imageButton, imageButton1, imageButton2, imageButton3;
```

Comment: With over 1000 of them, that's not much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
nButtons = 1000
std::vector<ImageButton> images;
images.assign(nButtons, ImageButton())
```

Answer (score -1):

What of this ? :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class ImageButton
{

};



int main()
{


    int i;
    int BUTTONSIZE=32*32;    // 32x32 pixels
    int BUTTONAMOUNT=1000;     // 1000 buttons


    ImageButton **imagebutton = 0;

    //memory allocated for 1000 elements , BUTTONAMOUNT=1000
    imagebutton = new ImageButton *[BUTTONAMOUNT] ;


    //memory allocated for  elements of each button.
    for(   i = 0 ; i < BUTTONAMOUNT ; i++ ) 
    {
        imagebutton[i] = new ImageButton[BUTTONSIZE];
        cout<<i<<".  \n";
    }


    //free the allocated memory
    for(   i = 0 ; i < BUTTONAMOUNT ; i++ )     delete [] imagebutton[i] ;
    delete [] imagebutton ;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting Null Void but I've already solved my problem using an array.  Thanks for the input